# Why is Lazy<T> not being lazy?

Tags: c#, lazy-initialization

I have several simple database queries using Entity Framework that I would like to load once using [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) but I can see that the query is executed every time the property is called. Variations I have tried are:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Foos => new Lazy<IEnumerable<string>>(() => _db.Foos.Select(x => x.Name)).Value;

public static IEnumerable<string> Foos=> new Lazy<IEnumerable<string>>(() => _db.Foos.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray()).Value;

public static Lazy<IEnumerable<string>> Foos => new Lazy<IEnumerable<string>>(() => _db.Foos.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray());

public static IEnumerable<string> LightingEnvironments
{
    get
    {
        var lazy = new Lazy<IEnumerable<string>>(() => _db.Foos.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray());
        return lazy.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because you are using it wrong. Create the instance outside of the property and access the value within the property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're constructing a new `Lazy` each time you call the property getter.  A `Lazy` only allows you to re-use an already constructed value if you *keep the `Lazy` instance around* and call the `Value` property *on the same `Lazy` instance* each time you need the value.